# Form with file input field wierdness

Tags: php, html

Ok. I'm probably just to tired to spot an issue here. The problem is when I submit this form, the attached file does not get submitted. $_FILES array in PHP is always empty.

Here is HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="navigator.php?kam=editovatElearningKurz&id=-13">
  <dl>
   <dt>
    <label for="documentName">Názov dokumentu</label>
   </dt>
   <dd>
    <input type="text" name="documentName" id="documentName" value="" />
   </dd>
   <dt>
    <label for="document">Dokument, ktorý chcete pridať ku kurzu</label>
   </dt>
   <dd>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    <input type="file" name="document" id="document" />
   </dd>
   <dt>
    &nbsp;
   </dt>
   <dd>
    <input type="submit" name="pridatDokument" id="pridatDokument" value="Pridať dokument" />
   </dd>
  </dl>
 </form>
```

In PHP I do:

```
if (isset($_POST['pridatDokument'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

The array is always empty. I've been trying to spot the mistake for some time now but it seems my blurry eyes can't do it at this evening hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ecntyp instead of enctype

Comment: Spot on. That was the problem.